# MongoDB java driver 3.2: parsing Json String to ArrayList<Document>

Tags: java, json, mongodb, mongodb-java

In earlier versions of Java driver, JSON.parse used to work for parsing a Json String into BasicDBObject or BasicDBList. But in the newer java drivers, BasicDBObject is now moved to Document and BasicDBList is moved to ArrayList. Document.parse can be used for parsing a Json String to Document, but I could not find anything equivalent for parsing Json String array to ArrayList. JSON.parse would still return a BasicDBList instead of ArrayList , and hence a ArrayList ,for example, would crash since individual element cannot be cast into Document.

The problem is not typecasting here. JSON.parse will return a BasicDBList which upon typecasting to ArrayList will still remain a BasicDBList since ArrayList being a superclass. The problem is parsing a json string array to ArrayList and maybe more speciafically lack of codecs (though there is a codec for BasicDBObject, there isnt one for BasicDBList). Is there any working/standard solution for this?

My code snippets:

```
ArrayList<Document> category = (ArrayList<Document>) JSON.parse(((requestBody.getArgumentByKey("category")).toString()));
```

This crashes at:

```
((Document) category.get(0))
```

with following message:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.mongodb.BasicDBObject cannot be cast to org.bson.Document
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`JSON.parse()` will return, for lack of a better term, legacy types.  You'll get back a `List<DBObject>`.  `DBObject`s aren't `Document`s and can't be cast like that.  To use `JSON.parse()` you'll need to continue using `DBObject` or pass those `DBObject`s to the constructor for `Document` that takes a `Map`.

Comment: Yes, that does work. But I dont want to continue using DBObject, rather shift to new recommended Document. So, basically looking for JSON.parse() equivalent for ArrayList<Document> . Similar to how Document.parse() is JSON.parse() equivalent for the Document .